# Start of a Schengen visa's validity period

Tags: schengen, planning

If I have a Schengen visa example starting from 1 August can I take a plane leaving my country at 31 July but reach my destination at 1 August or do I have to also ride the plane from my country 1 August?

Comment: You can leave whenever you want, what matters is the time you present yourself to the border check in the first Schengen country you will enter (not necessarily your final destination if you have a transit elsewhere in the Schengen area).